# Why can't I pass value using prepareForSegue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I have two `UIViewControllers` .In A `ViewController` I have code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ToResetPwd_NumberSegue"])
{
    ResetPwdBySmsCodeViewController* vc = (ResetPwdBySmsCodeViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
    vc.phone_no = _TF_phoneOrEmail.text;//TF_phoneOrEmail is a UITextField
    vc.test = @"dagaga";
}

}
```

In B   .h
I have code

```
@interface ResetPwdBySmsCodeViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *phone_no;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *test;
@end
```

In B .m

I can get the value of `_test`,but not `_phone_no`

I am sure that `vc.phone` is well in the `prepareForSegue`

Comment: `_TF_phoneOrEmail.text` print its value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should declare the 2 properties in B ViewController as `strong` or even better as `copy`:

```
@interface ResetPwdBySmsCodeViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *phone_no;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *test;
@end
```

The reason why you can get `_test` is that you are assigning it a literal string value, which is allocated by the compiler in a specific memory area. It is thus never deallocated and the `weak` variable will indefinitely point at it (until you explicitly assign a new value to `_test`, that is.)

On the other hand, you assign `vc.phone_no` a property from another object that might not exist anymore when you access the `weak` property (since a `weak` property is nil-ed when the object it points to is deallocated.) Hence the need for `strong` or `copy`.

Comment: could you tell me why can it work in UITableViewController ,because I use the same way to pass value and successed!

Comment: a `UITableViewController` will only display cells that are needed, as you know. now, what is likely happening is that text field you are getting the value from belongs to a cell that the table view controller deallocates. in short, you do not control when the cell is deallocated...

Comment: @sergio checkout my answer. I think you are wrong about a small point. Do let me know what you think.

Comment: @iRaviiVooda: it seems that your answer sums up to saying: a literal is never deallocated. that is what I stated in my answer, also. On the other hand, I cannot see how changing `test` value (i.e., assigning to it a different value), will cause any harm. It won't, simply it will be pointing to a different object or be `nil`...

Comment: @sergio: Yes, it you are assigning a different chunk of memory on to the `_test` pointer, it will not cause any problems. But, before you assign other memory, if you try to perform any mutational operations on the current memory you will crash. I think I have misunderstood your sentence slightly a little bit. But still there is a point which I'm adding to your response.

Comment: @iRaviiVooda: I see. I modified my answer to remove any ambiguity, I hope. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @sergio response, I want to explain why the first one `_TF_phoneOrEmail` did not work, but the second one did. This you will find only in case of `String` and `NSString`'s.

Your `_TF_phoneOrEmail` is an object created on runtime. The compiler generates code (instructions) in allocing, initing and incrementing reference count. Hence while you navigate from one controller to another since you are assigning a `weak` reference, the reference count is not incremented. (You should rather try with `assign` or `copy` like @sergio has mentioned).

On the other hand, when you declare `test`, the pointers are generated by compilers, but take the `@"dagga"` object. This is interesting. This is a inbuilt optimisation in C, that when you declare a string (Note: not a `String` instance) the instructions to create the new object instance of `String` holding the value (`@"dagga"`) are not generated. If you have come across process and threads internals, you will realise there is a memory segment called `Code` in the process memory. The process (which basically executes the instructions generated by compiler) itself, doesn't have enough permissions to write to this memory: it can only read from it. The `String` object (whose instructions are not generated by the compiler) is created in this memory. It's not exactly a object, its just a direct memory holding the value(`@"dagga"`).

So even, @sergio was wrong when he mentioned "until you explicitly change its value, that is". You cannot. Try manipulating the string (_test) and your app will crash.

If you had declared it as `[NSString stringWithString:@"dagga"]`, the compiler would have generated the instructions to create an object instance in heap/stack memory, but you declared as a literal, which cannot be deallocated at any executing time of the process.

Hope I'm clear.

Comment: I think I should learn more English ):,I know a little English.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your properties either strong or copy to claim ownership for the memory. You have them set to weak, which means you don't claim ownership and the data will disappear if no other variable has a strong reference to the data.

You always want to use copy for NSString objects because there is a mutable version of NSString, which means that your data could be changed without you realizing it.

```
@interface ResetPwdBySmsCodeViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *phone_no;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *test;
@end
```